# Ignore virtual keyboard when positioning views (Appcelerator Android)

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a view in appcelerator, here is the styling in the TSS file:

```
"#addTelephoneNumber" : {
  bottom: "10dp",
  height: "60dp",
  width: "100%",
  backgroundColor: "#FBB450",
  borderRadius: 10
}
```

I want it to be at the bottom of the screen, however when the keyboard shows, the view moves up. See screenshots below:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Can the keyboard be ignored and overlap the 'Add number' button? I have tried using top and setting it to 90% however same problem. Setting fixed values in dp fixes the issue, however it does not scale correctly on different mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

There's two properties to configure this behaviour:

- [Ti.UI.Window.windowSoftInputMode](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode) to determine **when** the soft keyboard shows as well as **how** the content adjusts to make room.
- [Ti.UI.View.softKeyboardOnFocus](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-softKeyboardOnFocus) to override the **when** per (input) view.